# access div tag inside form tag of master page

Tags: c#, html

I have a div inside the form tag of master page.
I want to change it dynamically as and when a page loads.
I am building a e-commerce web site where in I have a cart icon along with which I display the total amount corresponding to a user.
This Cart tag and the amount tag is inside the form tag of master page and I cannot find it from the code behind using HtmlGenericControl.

C# code

```
HtmlGenericControl myObject = new HtmlGenericControl();
myObject = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("simpleCart_total");
```

Html code

```
<div class="ca-r">
    <div class="cart box_1">
        <a href="../ShoppingCart.aspx">
           <h3> <div class="total">
              <span class="simpleCart_total" runat="server" style="display:none"></span> </div>
               <img src="/images/cart.png" alt=""/></h3>
                            </a>
```

How do i access the simpleCart_total from code behind of master page itself to change it accordingly.
Please Help
Thank You

Comment: do you need jquery solution

Comment: Without `id` property on the control how are you trying to find it? Also try with some ASP.NET panel control as well if you would be able to find.

Comment: will jquery be a good solution if this has to be applied to all my pages @Rahul

Comment: I have previously used "class" to find the tag and it works pretty well @SivaGopal

Comment: @Sagar yes it will be

Comment: Can you provide the code for it please @Rahul

Comment: I got it using id .Thanks @SivaGopal

Comment: good for you @Sagar